# Determine whether TRIM commands are being sent

Tags: ssd, trim

I've configured multiple SSDs in a RAID-0 array in AHCI mode. I'd like to determine whether TRIM commands are being sent to the disks. Is there a way to monitor these commands in the kernel somewhere? I'd just like to double-check to make sure that they *are*, in fact, being sent.

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative.

Comment: test whether trim works: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85880/30851

Comment: I'm curious, why have you configured multiple SSDs in RAID-0? I'm curious what kind of insane workload requires that much I/O, and yet doesn't require reliability.

Comment: Sometimes, you just gotta live on the edge man.

Comment: That, and have an awesome backup solution.