# How do I check TRIM?

Tags: ext4, ssd, storage, trim, fstrim

I have Linux installed on a Dell XPS 9343 with an Samsung PM851 SSD.
I recently read that many SSDs don't support TRIM operations.
So I'd like to check if `discard` option effectively works on my system.

At first step, I tried to simply run `sudo fstrim --verbose --all` and it reported `41GB trimmed`; this makes me fear because I was expecting a really little value because I have the continuously TRIM enabled (see above); in fact, if I re-run that command again I get `O bytes trimmed`. *Is it normal?* *even if I have the discard option in the /etc/fstab?*

PS: I tried to follow the proposed solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85880) but it stucks on the second command due to `trim.test: FIBMAP unsupported`.
PS2: it's a *flat* SSD (no LVM or RAID) with GPT and EXT4 filesystem

Comment: fstrim is basically saying you have 41G of free space on your partition. Are you sure you put your trim.test file on your ext4 filesystem? For example, filefrag will not work on a tmpfs like /tmp.

Comment: you are right! I don't have to run it on my /tmp, that is a tmpfs partition...I will answer my own question below.

Comment: anyhow, I don't understand why the first time I launch `sudo fstrim --verbose --all`, it reports `N GB trimmed`, while when I re-run it immediately after, I get `0 bytes trimmed` - OP updated to reflect this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @meuh pointed out in the comment, I need to run the test on my EXT4 partition, while I tried it on my /tmp
SOLVED!

PS: following the test result, I can confirm that the drive on my XPS 9343 (Samsung PM851 M.2 2280 256GB, firmware revision:  EXT25D0Q) supports TRIM command, even if dmesg reports `NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported`

Answer (score 17):

Try `lsblk -D`

TRIM/discard is available, if the `DISC-MAX` column is not `0B`

Example (SSD/trim available)

```
[root@foo bar]# lsblk -D
NAME   DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
sda           0        4K       1G         0
```

Example (HDD/trim not available)

```
[root@foo bar]# lsblk -D
NAME   DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO
sda           0        0B       0B         0
```

Comment: `DISC-MAX` is not a reliable indicator. `lsblk -D` shows me non-zero (`64M`) for my SD card `mmcblk0`, which has not `TRIM`.

Comment: @MartinVegter Technically it might have TRIM, as the flash chips are mostly identical, they just add a controller in front of it to translate between the flash and the SD interface. Though from what i know the SD Spec does not include TRIM, so this is would count as one of the cases of broken TRIM implementations like some SSDs which announce TRIM but have no or a broken implementation.

Comment: So in summary: if `DISC-MAX` is `0B` then you cannot use TRIM commands. Otherwise, YMMV.