# Erase external SSD completely, including SWAP

Tags: linux, dd, ssd, external-hdd, delete

I have an external SSD which I need completely wiped. I had Mint installed on it, with SWAP and some `root` dir. Those I somehow cannot get rid off. I tried `sudo dd` but that just wipes `sdc` and those other two entries seem to be separate from `sdc`, so my question is how to get rid off those (`sr0` and `zram0`), wiped? Here image... [image: screenshot of my external ssd]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mention the device from which Linux has booted.

`sr0` is a CDROM or DVD and is not what you really want to erase. With an erasable disc (CD-RW) if you really want to erase it, you can try `cdrecord -v blank=fast dev=/dev/sr0`. Of course, you will have some trouble if you erase a device from which you have booted.

`zram0` is a compressed view of your RAM. Just switch the PC off or reboot and `zram0` will be erased.

Answer (score 0):

- `sr0` is the cd/dvd reader, the `0` represents the first device on the scsi controller.  Either do a web search on *linux what is sr0* or someone else can explain the history behind this naming convention.  Pretty much `/dev/sr0` these days is your cd/dvd reader, as also shown by the `rom` under that last column which would have `TYPE` as the column name.
- `zram0` is in RAM

  - https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/blockdev/zram.html
  - sorry don't know much about it, but this is technically not your SSD, and what is copied from the SSD to this *swap* space in memory would be cleared on reboot, assuming you are using traditional DIMM RAM and not some non-volative ram like intel optane which retains data when powered off
  - if you need to go hardcore wipe data mode, do something like `dd if=/dev/zero of=<zram mount?>` I don't have enough to go on per your pic for the `of=`.

use `lsblk -o size,fstype,model,name,serial,uuid' to see more descriptive` lsblk` output to understand what you working with to be sure.

Given your pic, if `/sdc` is your SSD that you want to erase, having those 3 partitions on it, this is how I would do it

- `/parted /dev/sdc`

  - `mklabel gpt`
  - *type yes when prompted about gpt erasing all data on disk*
  - `mkpart primary 0% 100%`
  - `quit`
- `mkfs.xfs /dev/sdc` or `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc`
- `lsblk -o size,fstype,model,name,serial,uuid'
- verify from lsblk output just one partition */dev/sdc1* of correct FSTYPE per your `mkfs` choice, which will spanning the entire disk.  At this point the disk is pretty much clean.
- Because it is an SSD, take advantage of TRIM to securely erase the disk.  Older SSD's are a mixed bag when it comes to what their controllers support in terms of ATA functionality.

  - `mount /dev/sdc1 /myssd`
  - `fstrim --verbose /myssd`
- [How do I check TRIM?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306229/how-do-i-check-trim)
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive

  - use `lsblk --discard` to see if TRIM is available
  - *check the values of DISC-GRAN (discard granularity) and DISC-MAX (discard max bytes) columns. Non-zero values indicate TRIM support. For SATA SSDs only, the hdparm package can detect TRIM support via `hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep TRIM` as the root user. `hdparm` does however not support NVMe SSDswhere the `DISC-MAX` column is NOT set to `0B`.*

To *wipe* the *disk*, after you have remade the GPT partition label on it and made just 1 partition spanning the entire disk, you could do `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc1 count=? bs=?` using correct blocksize and count values to push all zeros onto the partition.  Doing it once not a big deal, doing it recklessly often would reduce the life of the SSD.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkdiscard.8.html

and there is also `blkdiscard` : *used to discard device sectors, useful for solid-state drivers (SSDs) and thinly-provisioned storage, Unlike fstrim this command is used directly on the block device.*