# Why doesn't accessing /dev/loopX raw update correctly (in real-time) when contents are modified?

Tags: filesystems, mount, block-device, loopback

If I create a file, such as `/tmp/vdev` (400KB in size and formatted to ext4) then map it to `/dev/loop18`, and then mount the `/dev/loop18` to `/tmp/mnt`, and then create a text file under `/tmp/mnt` and write various phrases to it while keeping `/tmp/vdev` & `/dev/loop18` each open in a separate hex editor, then I notice `/tmp/vdev` always updates in real-time when I save the text file. But `/dev/loop18` always shows old content from the last mount operation, and doesn't update until I unmount it. This is the case irrespective if I mount it with `-o sync` or not. Is there a reason for this, and how can I force `/dev/loop18` to update in real-time (on actual modifications to disk such as a save operation)?

Comment: you can drop cache, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/760335/30851